# Get values ​from a list

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm migrating code from version 2.5 to 3.0.5 of flutter.

The list values ​​after migrating the codes appear as empty when running the debug and the field appears as empty.

Even with the suggested changes, the list I defined as b023 cannot receive values ​​from a list called B023_XXXX.

The image shows the error that occurred in 'snapshot.data' besides not getting the values ​​stored in my list 'B023_RepVirtual'

```
if (snapshot.hasData) {
 if (snapshot.data()[1] != null) {
 if (snapshot.data![2] != null) {
   final List<B023_RepVirtual>? temp1 =
   snapshot.data()[1] as dynamic;
   print("Saindo do mapa: Dados mapa " + '$B023');
   final List<B024_RelacionaPessoaRepVirtual> temp2 =
   snapshot.data!()[2] as dynamic;
   temp2.forEach((e1) {
   final temp3 = temp1?.where((e2) =>
   e2.B023_ID == e1.B023_IDRep &&
   e1.B024_DataLiberacao != "0001-01-01T00:00:00");
      if (temp3?.length != 0) {
        final temp4 = temp3?.first;
         B023.add(temp4!);
         B023_Empresas.add(temp4);
         print("Saindo do mapa: Dados mapa " + '$B023');
   } else {
         final b = B023_RepVirtual();
         b.B023_NomeFantasia = "Falha ao buscar empresas!";
         B023.add(b);
         B023_Empresas.add(b);
         print("Saindo do mapa: Dados mapa "+ '$B023');
      }
    });
  }
```

Question: How do I get values ​​from one list to another inside a 'SingleChildScrollView'?

[image]

```
override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("Empresas: " + '$B023');

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Minha Conta"),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          child: FutureBuilder(
              future: _getMultiplasFuture(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                  case ConnectionState.none:
                  case ConnectionState.waiting:
                    return MinhaContaPlaceholder();
                  case ConnectionState.active:
                  case ConnectionState.done:
                    //List<B023_RepVirtual> B023 = <B023_RepVirtual>[];
                    List<B023_RepVirtual> B023 =
                        snapshot.data as List<B023_RepVirtual>;
                    List<B023_RepVirtual> B023_Empresas =
                        snapshot.data as List<B023_RepVirtual>;
                    print("Dentro do Conncetion Statte: " + '$B023');
                    print("Dentro do Conncetion Statte: " + '$B023_Empresas');

                    if (snapshot.hasData) {
                      if (snapshot.data()[1] != null) {
                        if (snapshot.data![2] != null) {
                          final List<B023_RepVirtual>? temp1 =
                              snapshot.data()[1] as dynamic;
                          print("Saindo do mapa: Dados mapa " + '$B023');
                          final List<B024_RelacionaPessoaRepVirtual> temp2 =
                              snapshot.data!()[2] as dynamic;
                          temp2.forEach((e1) {
                            final temp3 = temp1?.where((e2) =>
                                e2.B023_ID == e1.B023_IDRep &&
                                e1.B024_DataLiberacao != "0001-01-01T00:00:00");
                            if (temp3?.length != 0) {
                              final temp4 = temp3?.first;
                              B023.add(temp4!);
                              B023_Empresas.add(temp4);
                              print("Saindo do mapa: Dados mapa " + '$B023');
                            } else {
                              final b = B023_RepVirtual();
                              b.B023_NomeFantasia = "Falha ao buscar empresas!";
                              B023.add(b);
                              B023_Empresas.add(b);
                              print("Saindo do mapa: Dados mapa " + '$B023');
                            }
                          });
                        }
                      }
                    }
                    return Column(children: [
                      Container(
                        child: CircleAvatar(
                          backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade300,
                          child: Icon(
                            Icons.person,
                            size: 64.0,
                            color: Colors.orange,
                          ),
                          radius: 64.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        child: MinhaContaCardEmpresas(B023),
                      ),
                      Divider(color: Colors.transparent),
                      Divider(color: Colors.transparent),
                      GestureDetector(
                        child: Text("Termos de política e privacidade"),
                        onTap: () {
                          Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) =>
                                  ScreenTermosPoliticaPrivacidade(),
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                      Divider(color: Colors.transparent),
                      Container(
                        height: 24,
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                        child: GestureDetector(
                          child: Center(child: Text("Deletar minha conta")),
                          onTap: () {
                            confirmarMarcacoes(context);
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        height: 24,
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                        child: GestureDetector(
                          child: Center(child: Text("Versão: " + "1.0.1")),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ]);
                }
                ;
              })),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant perform like this widget tree, you can only use conditional if or ternary expression.

```
if(a<b) Text("A")
else Text("B"),
```

Or

```dart
a<b? Text("a is small"):Text("a is not small"),
```

Now to have function inside widget, you can use inline function but not recommended for heavy operation.

```dart
[
  (){
  /// your method and others stuff
  return Text("return  widget");
}(),
]
```

Or better perform before everything before returning a widget like before `ModalProgressHUD`
Make sure the syntax is ok like `(){yourOperation}()`

Comment: I confess that I didn't understand very well.

I understand that I cannot use the comparison:
snapshot.data()[1] != null )

.And yes, it should compare an expression like:
a<b? Text("a is small"):Text("a is not small"),


Correct?